# Wrong Ruby Interpreter being used

Tags: ruby, rvm, eventmachine

I'm trying to setup Apache/Thin to power my Rails 3.2.9 application, which means setting up both Apache and Thin as daemons. I'm using RVM/gemset that runs Ruby 1.9.3-p286, however, my daemons don't seem to want to use it, instead, opting for some non-RVM system installed Ruby 1.8.7.

When I go to start thin, this is the error I receive:

```
ubuntu@ip-1-1-1-1:~/www/mydomain/mysite$ /etc/init.d/thin start
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286@mysite/gems/eventmachine-1.0.0/lib/rubyeventmachine.so: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 1.8.7 (2011-06-30 patchlevel 352) [x86_64-linux]

Aborted (core dumped)
```

Similarly, using the same command with `sudo` yields:

```
ubuntu@ip-1-1-1-1:~$ sudo /etc/init.d/thin start
[start] /etc/thin/mysite.yml ...
Starting server on 127.0.0.1:5000 ... 

# However, it refuses connections and crashes, evidenced by:
ubuntu@ip-1-1-1-1:~/www/mydomain/mysite/log$ cat thin.5000.log
>> Writing PID to tmp/pids/thin.5000.pid
>> Using rack adapter
>> Exiting!
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require': no such file to load -- bundler/setup  (LoadError)
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
...
```

I think the segmentation fault is due to the wrong version of Ruby. Clearly, it is using 1.8.7, which isn't the Ruby I want. However, checking the ruby version otherwise seems to look OK:

```
ubuntu@ip-1-1-1-1:~$ which ruby
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/bin/ruby
ubuntu@ip-1-1-1-1:~$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p286 (2012-10-12 revision 37165) [x86_64-linux]
```

And here it is again run under `sudo`:

```
ubuntu@ip-1-1-1-1:~$ sudo which ruby
/usr/bin/ruby
ubuntu@ip-1-1-1-1:~$ sudo ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p0 (2011-10-30 revision 33570) [x86_64-linux]
```

How do I get my system to use Ruby 1.9.3 when I run Thin as a daemon, and avoid these nasty errors?

**EDIT:**

Here's what my /etc/init.d/thin file looks like (it's auto-generated using thin install, I believe):

```
#!/bin/sh
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          thin
# Required-Start:    $local_fs $remote_fs
# Required-Stop:     $local_fs $remote_fs
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      S 0 1 6
# Short-Description: thin initscript
# Description:       thin
### END INIT INFO

# Original author: Forrest Robertson

# Do NOT "set -e"

DAEMON=/usr/local/bin/thin
SCRIPT_NAME=/etc/init.d/thin
CONFIG_PATH=/etc/thin

# Exit if the package is not installed
[ -x "$DAEMON" ] || exit 0

case "$1" in
  start)
        $DAEMON start --all $CONFIG_PATH
        ;;
  stop)
        $DAEMON stop --all $CONFIG_PATH
        ;;
  restart)
        $DAEMON restart --all $CONFIG_PATH
        ;;
  *)
        echo "Usage: $SCRIPT_NAME {start|stop|restart}" >&2
        exit 3
        ;;
esac
```

- Dave

Comment: Found this, is it relevant? https://rvm.io/integration/init-d/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out (or at least, I got it working one way...)

Using [this](https://rvm.io/integration/init-d/) suggestion on the RVM site...

1. Make sure your service (in my case, `thin`) is installed in one of your RVM gemsets.
2. Generate a wrapper using: `rvm wrapper ruby-1.9.3@mygemset bootup thin`, replacing parameters as appropriate to your installation. It will make a script `/usr/local/rvm/bin/bootup_thin`. This wrapper will load thin with the gemset you specified in your call.
3. Edit the `/etc/init.d/thin` script. Make the script call the generated Ruby wrapper by setting `DAEMON=/usr/local/bin/thin` to `DAEMON=/usr/local/rvm/bin/bootup_thin`
4. Run your daemon; it should use the correct Ruby environment now.
5. An unrelated 'gotcha' I ran into immediately after getting over this hurdle had to do with missing gems needed by my application. I think it has to do with different gemsets being used between my application folder and the daemon. You might have to do what I did; navigate to the application root, explicitly change to the gemset used by the daemon with `rvm gemset use`, then run `bundle install` to install the necessary gems into the gemset used by the daemon.

With that, I got my server running with Apache/Thin. For those looking to do the same, use these pages.

1st: http://articles.slicehost.com/2008/5/6/ubuntu-hardy-thin-web-server-for-ruby

2nd: http://articles.slicehost.com/2008/5/6/ubuntu-hardy-apache-rails-and-thin

Comment: David, What is mygemset here? I have my Rails app installed in a separate directory.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit /etc/init.d/thin and change this part:

```
run_action() {
        ACTION="$1"

        if [ -x /usr/bin/ruby1.8 ]; then
            /usr/bin/ruby1.8 $DAEMON $ACTION --all /etc/thin1.8
        fi

        if [ -x /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 ]; then
            /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 $DAEMON $ACTION --all /etc/thin1.9.1
        fi

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. My script doesn't appear to have any explicit references to 1.8... I don't know how to modify it with this. Can you take a look at my edit above?